# How I can change a value in a csv. using a slide bar in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, slider, shinydashboard, uislider

(and thanks in advance for your help)

I'm trying to create a slidebar in my Shiny App. This bar has to be capable to change the value of % of chlorine in a modeling process. I mean that you initate your model with a fixed value that you can find in a csv. and then, the bar has to change this value, and of course, change the modeling results.

I coded that for UI and SERVE:

UI

````
            mainPanel(
              fluidRow(
                  column(12,
                      h3("Modificacio de Clor"),    #title
                      p("Tria de percentatge per a modificar el Clor a la xarxa"),  #subtitle
                      sliderInput(inputId = "clor_modif", label = "% Clor:", min = -1, max = 1, value = 
                                  0.75, step = 0.05, round = T), #sliderInput with relevant information of 
                                                                 #my bar 
                     )
                  )
               )
            
    ),```

```shinyServer(function(input, output) {

observe({
     #Database where the parameter of chlorine is saved
      simulation_parameters_zona <- read.csv("./data/simulation_parameters_zona.csv", header = TRUE) 
     #The parameter is in 8th file
      simulation_parameters_zona <- simulation_parameters_zona[8,]
     
     #I want the slidebar change the value and the value will be recorded in the csv. 
     #(simulation_parameters_zona). Because when we re-run the modeling, the shiny app takes into account 
     #the new value, and then changes de result of the model.
      
      val <- input$clor_modif
      updateSliderInput(session, val, value = simulation_parameters_zona$dades2*val)
      
    })
})```

Actually, I tried several times how I could attach the bar to the file, but I can't... I'm sorry if the question is dumb (I'm sure about it). I'm a beginner with Shiny...




***Thank you very much for your help!***
````

Comment: `updateSliderInput` requires `session`, so you probably want `shinyServer(function(input, output, server) { ... })`...and you probably need an `inputId` in `updateSliderInput` which in this case is `clormodif`...something like `updateSliderInput(session, inputId = clor_modif, value = ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem.... It was easier than I thought, and I let start with the explanation! :)

The problem was I couldn't call the row number 8 of my dataset simulation_parameters_zona because I was using wrong the nomenclature!

The correct answer for my question is:

```
 observe({
      simulation_parameters_zona <- read.csv("./data/simulation_parameters_zona.csv", 
header = TRUE)
      simulation_parameters_zona$dades2[8] <- input$clor_modif
      write.csv(simulation_parameters_zona,"./data/simulation_parameters_zona.csv", 
row.names = FALSE)
      print(input$clor_modif)
    })
```

This allows a sidebar the capacity to change the number as an input in the simulation_parameter_zona.csv and it changes the simulation each time somebody change that bar.

I hope this can help anybody else! :)

Cheers!